# Can we open a flutter project created in Android Studio, in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, setup-project

I am using VSCode for Flutter development but my team is using Android Studio. So when I tried to clone the repo which has Flutter Project created from Android Studio into VSCode, it is not even detecting import 'package: flutter/material.dart'; and throwing a lot of errors.

Is there a way possible or is it like we cannot use other code editors for projects created in Android.

Comment: File>Open Folder>Inside Your Project Folder> Select

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. Just open your terminal and enter the following commands

```
cd my-project-folder/
#takes you to your project folder
```

then

```
code .
#this will open your project in vs code
```

Comment: Or more simply: `code my-project-folder`... identical behavior.  Even the embedded terminal starts out *inside* your project at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but make sure VS Code is correctly set up. It needs to have Flutter and Dart Extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's easy

1. Open VS Code
2. Open terminal ( press CTRL + ~ ) or ( from top bar press view >> command palette and select Create New Terminal )
3. Copy your project path and add it to terminal

   To add the path to terminal  type

   `cd type/your/path`

   then type `code .` in terminal to open your file